# FileWatcher - NullObjectReference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating FileWatcher and I'm adding watcher_Changed method as event.
After some time it crashes in catch section as **NullReferenceObject** (IIS Express error).

```
private static void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        fWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
        var newLoc = ReadLines();
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub1>();
        //Do something
        fWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
//Error appears here
        fWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        fWatcher = null;
        fWatcher.Dispose();
        fWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        while (fWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents != true)
        {
            try
            {
                fWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {                    
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

        }

    } 
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can start fixing it by using debugger to determine which object is null. My guess is that Garbage Collector munched fWatcher after Session/Application life time ended. You get null in fWatcher and then you call its property...

Comment: Are you sure you have initiated fWatcher? Can you give us full code?

Comment: MohammadMirMostafa: Yes, it's initiated, It works fine, but sometimes it crashes.
PTwr: Well, I have to check it, It could be that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  fWatcher = null;    //You cannot do this "fWatcher." after this line 
                      //(Until you call fWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher() at least)
  fWatcher.Dispose(); //You cannot do this !!!!!
```

If you want to dispose it ,call Dispose() First and then create a new one.
You cannot call a method on an object that is null

Comment: So, if my application will gets stuck and I'd like to reboot FileWatcher, I must delete line "fWatcher = null;", yes? I understood that I can't do anything when object is null. Just delete old and create new one?

Comment: fWatcher =null; does not delete the object.It only means that IF the garbage collector is called the object will be disposed.
So yes,delete that line